# Goal expansion for an `if_/3` operator in Prolog

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate, logical-purity

I'm writing a tokeniser and I want to use [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) to preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) in my code.

The code looks like the following code<sup>1</sup> on the left—but I want it to look like the one on the right.

```
if_(Cond1_1,                       %     (   Cond1_1
    Then1,                         %     *=> Then1
    if_(Cond2_1,                   %     ;   Cond2_1
        Then2,                     %     *=> Then2
        if_(Cond3_1,               %     ;   Cond3_1
            Then3,                 %     *=> Then3
            if_(Cond4_1,           %     ;   Cond4_1
                Then4,             %     *=> Then4
                if_(Cond5_1,       %     ;   Cond5_1
                    Then5,         %     *=> Then5
                    Else5          %     ;   Else5
   )   )   )   )   ).              %     ).
```

To do the rewriting of `(*=>)/2` to `if_/3` in SWI-Prolog I came up with:

```
:- op(1050,xfy,*=>).

:- multifile goal_expansion/2.
goal_expansion((Cond *=> Then ; Else), if_(Cond,Then,Else)).
goal_expansion( Cond *=> Then        , (call(Cond,true), call(Then))).
```

"*Done*," I thought...

But I became doubtful after reading the [SWI-Prolog documentation for `goal_expansion/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=goal_expansion/2):

> Only goals appearing in the body of clauses when reading a source file are expanded using this mechanism, and only if they appear literally in the clause, or as an argument to a defined meta-predicate that is annotated using `0' (see meta_predicate/1). *Other cases need a real predicate definition.*

So here's my actual question: **Do I need a real predicate definition, too?**

---

<sub>**Footnote 1**: The actual code has an even longer chain of `else if`s.</sub>

Comment: @false. Thx! Fixed.

Comment: Why do you want to do the rewriting and not write an explicit procedure to do the "switch" ?

Comment: @gusbro. Good question. I thought goal expansion is the more general way, but I'm having more and more doubts...

Comment: Also, meta_predicate/2 declarations help to clarify everything.

Comment: On rereading your question, I noted that your specific expansion is not valid for error cases like `?- =(nonbool)  *=> true .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a if_/3 predicate definition, to at least assign
it a meta predicate declaration, otherwise expansion will stop,
if there is no meta predicate declaration for if_/3 itself.

You can try yourself, I am using only this expansion:

```
:- op(1050,xfy,*=>).
:- multifile goal_expansion/2.
goal_expansion((Cond *=> Then ; Else), if_(Cond,Then,Else)).
```

Without meta predicate declaration:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.4)

?- expand_goal((a *=> b; c *=> d; e), X).
X = if_(a, b,  (c*=>d;e)).
```

With meta predicate declaration:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.4)

:- meta_predicate if_(1,0,0).
?- expand_goal((a *=> b; c *=> d; e), X).
X = if_(a, b, if_(c, d, e)).
```

This is same behaviour in SWI-Prolog and Jekejeke Prolog. You could study the source code to better understand why the meta predicate declaration is needed.

See for example here:
https://github.com/jburse/jekejeke-devel/blob/master/jekrun/headless/jekpro/frequent/standard/expand.p#L220